# Is there way to create a factory binding in kotlin kodein, which can produce null?

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, kodein

Is there way to create a factory binding, which can produce null?

For example,

```
bind<String?> with factory { x: Int -> 
    when (x) {
        1 -> "A"
        2 -> "B"
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `bind<String?>` gives error.

Answer (score 3):

End up with `Optional`:

```
bind<Optional<String>> with factory { x: Int -> 
    when (x) {
        1 -> Optional.of<String>("A")
        2 -> Optional.of<String>("B")
        else -> Optional.empty()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Null is not allowed by factories in Kodein.